# Multiple selection Form in Php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm trying to construct a drop down menu that allows the user to select multiple values, I query 2 values an id and a name from a database, I use the id as a value and the name as the description of the option. However the dropdown menu only allows me to select one option at a time. How can I allow multiple values to be selected and how do I handle the multiple values posted?

```
print"<select name='Category' id='nodes' size='4' multiple='multiple'>\n";
$db = adodbConnect();
$query = "Select * From nodes";
$result = $db -> Execute($query);
while($row=$result->FetchRow())
{
$cat = $row['id'];
$desc =$row['name'];
print "<option value='$cat'>$desc</option>\n";
}
print "</select>\n";
```

Comment: Dropdown as it is in given code will allow multiple selections (ctrl + click on the second item).

Comment: but how do I make it where the user can just click on them and select multiple options?

Comment: I've posted answer but I still don't recommend using one.

Comment: alrighty PLB thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: If it solves your problem, you should accept it as solution. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple select listbox without pressing CTRL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465796/multiple-select-listbox-without-pressing-ctrl)

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = adodbConnect();
$query = "Select * From nodes";
$result = $db -> Execute($query);
$select='';
$select.="<select name='Category' id='nodes' size='4' multiple='multiple'>\n";
while($row=$result->FetchRow())
{
$cat = $row['id'];
$desc =$row['name'];
$select.="<option value='$cat'>$desc</option>\n";
}
$select.="</select>\n";
echo $select;
```

at the post you will receive value in forms of array like if you select two option
than it will like `array('1','2')`

Comment: I implemented this in my code but it just printed all the values in plain text and there was no drop down anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle multiple values in php like-

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

foreach ($_GET['category'] as $selectedOption)
    echo $selectedOption."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: how did you come up with variable $selectedOption?

Comment: @user1902588 It is the syntax of foreach, All array items will be taken one by one in $selectedoption

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple values using a select in that way you just need to use the Cmd (Mac) or Ctrl (Windows) key and click on multiple.

To process the post:

```
<?php
  $categories = $_POST['category']; 

  foreach($categories as $category){
    //do stuff
  }
?>
```

Comment: how did you come up with the variable $category?

Comment: that is standard syntax for the foreach control structure. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

***Just Try With The Following :***

```
<?php
$db     = adodbConnect();
$query  = "Select * From nodes";
$result = $db -> Execute($query);
print "<select size=\"4\" multiple=\"multiple\" name=\"Category[]\">";
print "<option value='-' >Select from list</option>";
while ($row=$result->FetchRow()){
$cat  = $row['id'];
$desc = $row['name'];
print "<option value=$cat>$desc</option>";
}
print "</select>";
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Hey john I tried this and it just print all the element in my menu in plain text with no drop down menu there.

Comment: I'm using the following one in my local server it's working fine : can you check following one too : <?php
$con = mysql_connect("HOST_NAME","HOST_USER","HOST_PASSWORD");
$sel_db = mysql_select_db("DB_NAME",$con);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 50")or die(mysql_error());
print "<select size=\"4\" multiple=\"multiple\" name=\"Category[]\">";
print "<option value='-' >Select from list</option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$uid = $row['id'];
$desc =$row['name'];
print "<option value=$cat>$desc</option>";
}
print "</select>";
?>